# Create regex to replace the href in input value with single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I get from server the html (in plain text with ajax) with this value:

```
<input id="email_id" name="email_id" type="text" value="<a href="mailto:my@email.com">my@email.com</a>" />
```

Because of input value contains double quotes in rendered wrong. So I need to replace double quotes with single quotes to get this:

```
<input id="email_id" name="email_id" type="text" value="<a href='mailto:my@email.com'>my@email.com</a>" />
```

I understand that it should be something like this:

```
mystring.replace(/"/g, "'");
```

But how specify that a need to replace quotes only in `value` attribute?

Comment: Do you have any control over how the server sends this to you?

Comment: The server should be HTML-encoding the value for you, especially if you're using AJAX.

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have access to server-side code in this case.

Comment: @user1858864 see http://regex101.com/r/bW2jB4/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
mystring.replace(/href="([^"]+)"/g, "href='$1'");
```

Comment: With correction in the form of a closing parenthesis in firxt part of regex it works perfect, thanks! :)